# Substituir arquivos com izpack

Tags: java, izpack

Eu tenho um instalador que joga uns arquivos em uma pasta, porém eu queria usar o mesmo instalador para fazer o update da aplicação, com isso existem alguns arquivos que não podem ser sobrescritos. Desta forma eu pensei em mostrar uma caixa de diálogo quando o arquivo já existir perguntando se o usuário quer sobrescrever.

Meu código *izpack* é este

```xml
 <pack name="Product" required="yes">
            <file src="../@{project.artifactId}.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH" />
            <fileset dir="../resources" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/resources">
                <include name="**/*" />
            </fileset>

            <fileset dir="dependency" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/lib">
                <include name="**/*" />
            </fileset>

            <fileset dir="../resources/icons" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH">
                <include name="favicon.ico" />
            </fileset>

 </pack>
```

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver utilizando

```xml
<file src="../resources/myfile.properties" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/resources" override="false" />
<fileset dir="../resources" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/resources">
  <exclude name="**/myfile.properties" />
  <include name="**/*" />
</fileset>
```